# How to add specific tag to client using Quarkus and micrometer

Tags: kotlin, prometheus, quarkus, micrometer

I'm using Quarkus app in version `2.13.3.Final` and for metrics I'm using `quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus`.
The client looks like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "foo-api")
interface FooClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    fun findFoo(
        @QueryParam("foo") foo: String
    ): RestResponse
}
```

and then I'm getting a metric like

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="foo.com",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/foo",} 30.0
```

The problem is that I have more clients similar to `FooClient` calling the same domain (`foo.com/{thisVaries}`), so I need to add a tag to every client, then I could see the difference in metrics (otherwise I get `clientName="foo.com"` in every one of them). I know it's possible to add `commonTag`, but that doesn't solve my problem, it just adds the same tag to every metric. Is there any way how to solve it?

The result should look like this (mind the added tag `clientClass` at the end):

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="foo.com",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/foo",clientClass="AddressClient"} 30.0
http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="foo.com",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/foo",clientClass="NameClient"} 36.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by other clients calling the domain, however, if you want to add a specific tag to that client, you can create a custom ClientRequestFilter, this way:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MeterProvider implements ClientRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    MeterRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        registry.counter("http_client_requests_seconds_count",
                "client.class", requestContext.getClient().getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

You inject the Micrometer registry, select the right meeter and then add a custom tag to it.
Then, you need to register the filter into the client, like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "foo-api")
@RegisterProvider(MeterProvider.class)
interface FooClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    fun findFoo(
        @QueryParam("foo") foo: String
    ): RestResponse
}
```

The same filter can be reused in other clients.

Comment: Tried that, but I get `Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: http_client_requests_seconds_count is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector` error. I also tried to clear the registry before calling `registry.counter()` with `CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.clear()` and `registry.clear()`, but it didn't help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create that same metric, just use the existing one to add the tag...
I created a demo project for you... Please check: [quarkus-observability-demo-micrometer - MeterProvider](https://github.com/brunobat/quarkus-observability-demo/blob/main/quarkus-observability-demo-micrometer/src/main/java/com/brunobat/micrometer/client/MeterProvider.java)

Comment: Right, that's what I want - to use the existing one and add the custom tag (see edited question at the end, what the result should look like). But when I'm doing so, I get the error mentioned before in the comment. The demo is creating metric called `http_client_requests_total` with the custom tag, but no other tags (OUTCOME, uri, etc.), also the value of that metric is always `0`.